# Auto import XML files in Sparx Enterprise Architect repository

Tags: enterprise-architect

I would like to auto import XML files that contains information about changed packages, diagrams, elements, and so on to my repository on a MySQL server.

There is a functionality in the EA, located in "Import/Export" -> "Import package from XMI file". Is there any way to trigger that function from a script or from a program to automate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check the operation `ImportPackageXMI` in the [Project Interface](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.0/automation_and_scripting/project_2.html). You can use that operation from an add-in, external program or EA script.

Comment: Thanks. I will checkt that out.